# Blazor Static Server Rendering - Submitting Form Without Button

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-8.0

I would like to convert a Blazor server app to use static server rendering (SSR) as much as possible. I figured out that you have to use forms to capture and submit values in SSR mode.

I have a data table which I managed to render successfully in SSR. Now I have a drop-down filter list used to filter column values. When the user selects a value from the list, I'd like to reload the data table with the filtered data. Is there a way how I can do this without using a button to submit the form? I guess I can invoke some JavaScript to attach an event to the list, but I don't like this approach.

[image: data table]